# Incorrect behavior in case of connection error in Codename One ConnectionRequest

Tags: java, io, codenameone

I am experiencing a problem with the way the application behaves in case of a connection error.

When the User fills the user/pass fields I do the following:

```
  public static AuthenticationResponse authenticate (String username, String password){    
    return WebServiceCaller.authenticate(username, password, ServiceDefinitions.getAuthenticationServiceDefintion());
  }
```

In the web service caller I have:

```
public static AuthenticationResponse authenticate(String username, String password, ServiceDefinition definition) {
    AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(username, password);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().setTimeout(10000); // change the default timeout of network.
    service.setTimeout(10000); // change the default timeout of request connection
    service.setUrl(definition.getUrl());
    service.setContentType(definition.getContentType());
    service.setPost(definition.isPost());
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog dlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    service.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(authenticationService);    
    return authenticationService.getModelResponse();
}
```

I also overrode the `handleIoException` and `handleException` methods, so instead of showing the generic dialog, i fill a response object with a message and that message is shown in the GUI.

The incorrect thing that happens is that that the return part of the method above is called before the error management methods complete.

So basically it should be `call->wait->errorManagement` `complete->return` but instead I get `call->wait->errorManagement->return->errorManagemetnComplete`.

Maybe I am missing something in the way the network manager works and it’s multithreaded operation, if you have any more detailed documentation I would gladly read it.

What I do in the overriden methods is shown below:

```
/** Handles IOException thrown when performing a network operation */
@Override
protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
    Log.p("Handle IOException, when network is down! ");               
    manageGenericErrors();
}   

@Override
public void manageGenericErrors() {
    response.setIsSuccessful(false);
    response.setResponseMessage("Service not available”);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error handling goes first to the `NetworkManager` error listeners and only then invokes the handle methods (e.g. `handleException`).

This is important since you might want to globally handle errors differently e.g. if you have code such as:

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().addErrorListener((e) -> e.consume());
```

In this code you would effectively block all error handling in Codename One in a generic way and this must happen before the handle* methods are invoked since they show the error dialogs.

The `addToQueueAndWait` method blocks by listening to network/error events. On normal completion this works just fine but on error events you would get the error listener callback before the handle method would be called.  Since the generic `addToQueueAndWait` method can't override methods and should still work correctly if you defined that you don't want errors to be shown this is something that's core to the basic design of that API.

I don't see a generic way to get this to work differently. A workaround would be to use `NetworkManager`'s `addErrorListener()` instead of overriding these methods.